Woocommerce wordpress responsive images
I wondered if it's possible to make the WooCommerce thumbnail images responsive. Currently, there is only one image size for the thumbnails, and I would like to add the src set attribute with further image sizes. I saw that WooCommerce offers several possibilities to modify images (https://developer.woocommerce.com/docs/image-sizing-for-theme-developers/) but I don't know if and how it's possible to "combine" them with the responsive images functions from WordPress (https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/responsive-images/). Can anyone help me? :)
To change the image size, I used this code:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail_size', function( $size ) {
    return 'thumbnail';
} );

But that's as far as I got.

You can show the responsive image using the wp_get_attachment_image of WordPress. You need to use this where you want to show responsive image.
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'woocommerce_thumbnail', false, array(
        'sizes'   => '(max-width: 480px) 100vw, 50vw',
        'class'   => 'woocommerce-image',
) );

In the above code $attachment_id is the attachment id and woocommerce-image is the CSS class(you can change as per your need) we want to add.
woocommerce_thumbnail is the registered image thumbnail size which you can use as per your need.

Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I'm not sure I understood completely. If I use the code you send and paste it into code snippets, how will that contribute to making the woocommerce thumbnails responsive?

This will generate img tag with responsive images, you can give a try to this on local environment
